# Inserting image using another div's background image using JS

Tags: javascript

I want my hidden div to  show the clicked div's background image as an image src.How can i change my code to achieve that?
Best regards.

```
<div id="hidden_div"></div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
function func(element) {
var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
hidden.style.backgroundImage = element.style.backgroundImage;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Why would you set the background on a hidden `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to append an `<img>` element to your hidden div... Right ?

Then :

```
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(element) {
  var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
  // Create <img> element
  var imgElement = document.createElement("IMG"); // creating
  // backgroundImage contains url(path/to/image), we want to extract the quoted string
 imgElement.src=element.style.backgroundImage.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
 hidden.appendChild(imgElement);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-inline styles, you can read them with `window.getComputedStyle`:

```
function func(element) {
    var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
    hidden.style.backgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(element), null).getPropertyValue("background-image");
}
```